# Navigation Drawer Icon (ic_drawer) not showing

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am implementing a navigation drawer for my app. Now it works perfectly except for one small glitch. When I set the Navigation Drawer Icon (ic_drawer) to replace the regular "HomeAsUp" caret icon, I still get the arrow. The Nav Drawer icon does not show. I have implemented every method that was on the android developers website. But it doesn't seem to work.

Below is my code:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
FrameLayout leftDrawer, rightDrawer, contentFrame;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    initializeViews();
}

private void initializeViews() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mDrawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open_content_desc,
            R.string.drawer_close_content_desc);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    leftDrawer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLeft_frame);
    rightDrawer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerRight_frame);
    contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I know it is quite late to answer this but this would help someone atleast.

You should probably add these lines of code to show that navigation icon.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: In my case, that's what I was missing. Thank you. No meta-data needed in AndroidManifest. The accepted answer is not correct.

Comment: In my case it is working with this piece of code. When manifest meta-data added there is no reflection of drawer icon.

Answer (score 20):

Simply put this code in your styles.xml file:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
```

I had this same problem and this worked for me.

Programmatically you can set:
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);`

Answer (score 19):

You have to put this code:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

I hope that this code help you.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by having a `<meta-data>` specified for my activity but the android:value points to the same Activity.

Hence, if say Activity name is MainActivity then add the below tag to your activity in the manifest file.

```
<meta-data
     android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
     android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Making the `PARENT_ACTIVITY` meta tag point to the same activity in the manifest defeats the entire purpose of setting a parent activity. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: Yes, I do know. But somehow only this helped me. Anyways, I feel @Naveen Kumar has also answered correctly below. Please check that before this.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the AndroidManifest.xml, for the that specific activity **NOT** to have the meta-data `"android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"` set. Try removing the `<meta-data>` if it's set like this:

```
<activity> 
...
 <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.company.project.ParentActivity"/>
</activity>
```