# Navigation Drawer icon not showing android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ListView mDrawerList;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    public CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    public String[] navMenuTitles;
    public TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    public ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    TextView tvTitle, tvTitleNext;

    private Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack;
    private Stack<Integer> fragmentCount;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//      startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
//              UpdateDeviceToken.class));

        actionBar = getActionBar();


        fragmentStack = new Stack<Fragment>();
        fragmentCount = new Stack<Integer>();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(true));
        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this,
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(0);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
//      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//      getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

//      LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//      View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_t, null);
//
//      actionBar.setCustomView(v);

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F71D1D")));
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(null);
        View actionBarView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);
        tvTitle = (TextView)actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        tvTitleNext = (TextView)actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleNext);

        tvTitle.setTypeface(KkpMandir.app_ver);
        tvTitleNext.setTypeface(KkpMandir.app_ver);



        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_action_nav_menu, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                tvTitle.setText(mTitle);
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                tvTitle.setText(mDrawerTitle);
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            if (navDrawerItems.get(0).isImg()) {
                displayView(1);
                Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 1");
            } else {
                displayView(0);
                Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 0");
            }
        }

        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);

    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    public void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new HomeFragmentNew();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            if(fragmentStack.size()>0){
                fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
                ft.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            }
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft.commit();

            Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 1");

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new EventFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft1.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft1.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft1.commit();

            Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 2");
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft2.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft2.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft2.commit();
            Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 3");
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new OrganizationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft3 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft3.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft3.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft3.commit();
            Log.e("MAIN---->", "POSITION: 4");
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new PresidentMsgFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft4 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft4.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft4.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft4.commit();

            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new NewsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft5 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft5.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft5.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft5.commit();

            break;

        case 7:
            fragment = new VideoFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft6 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft6.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft6.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft6.commit();

            break;

        case 8:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft7 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft7.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft7.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft7.commit();

            break;

        case 9:
            fragment = new VoiceFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft8 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft8.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft8.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
            fragmentCount.push(position);
            ft8.commit();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

//      if (fragment != null) {
//          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                  .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//          mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position-1]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            // error in creating fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        tvTitle.setText(mTitle);
//      getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void showExitDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (fragmentStack.size() >1) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentCount.pop();
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
            ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());
            fragmentStack.lastElement().onResume();
            ft.show(fragmentStack.lastElement());
            ft.commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked((Integer)fragmentCount.lastElement(), true);
//          mDrawerList.setSelection((Integer)fragmentCount.lastElement());
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[(Integer)fragmentCount.lastElement()-1]);

        } else {
            showExitDialog();
        }


    }
}
```

above is my MainActivity file code. i implementing simple navigationdrawer with custom actionbar. that's why drawer icon not showing in some devices. if i used default actionbar than it works fine.

below is my output:

[image]

help me for solve this bug.

Comment: Is your drawable defined for all resolutions?

Comment: yes, its defined for all resolutions.

Comment: @Riser why don't you try this [sample](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip) and check [it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20385101/1761003)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(null);
```

with:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Solved it for me. Not sure what you did differen but it works. By the way, I'm using the SupportActionBar and it also works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

More correct answer is this.

As per warning from log,

W/ActionBarDrawerToggle(28554): DrawerToggle may not show up because Navigation Icon is not visible. You may need to call **actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**