# android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout is not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have been fallowing on a [touch + tutorials android beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMAb_oRDqGk) from a week, and i used android.support.v4.widget.Drawer Layout (drawer layout ) in my main.xml file. but its not working,i am not able to see drawer on toolbar.

error i am getiing is below

```
02-09 08:30:18.730 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-09 08:30:18.742 24972-24972/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-09 08:30:18.742 24972-24972/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-09 08:30:18.742 24972-24972/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17962: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-09 08:30:18.746 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-09 08:30:18.746 24972-24972/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-09 08:30:18.746 24972-24972/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17966: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-09 08:30:18.746 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-09 08:30:18.754 24972-24978/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-09 08:30:18.758 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 08:30:18.814 24972-24972/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 134K, 11% free 2451K/2728K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
02-09 08:30:18.826 24972-24972/? W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
02-09 08:30:18.838 24972-24972/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-09 08:30:18.842 24972-24972/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-09 08:30:18.842 24972-24972/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-09 08:30:18.874 24972-24972/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-09 08:30:18.886 24972-24972/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-09 08:30:18.890 24972-24975/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 45K, 7% free 2794K/3004K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 3ms
02-09 08:53:28.198 24972-24975/com.example.lucy.zoo D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 16% free 2799K/3320K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 4ms
```

The code is good but I don't know what is the issue. Can anyone please look into my code and suggest me where does the problem lie. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private DrawerLayout mdrawerlyout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

       mdrawerlyout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mdrawerlyout,R.string.drawer_opend,R.string.drawer_closed){
           @Override
           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
               if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {


                   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opend);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
               if(getSupportActionBar() !=null) {
                   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);
               }
           }
       };
         mdrawerlyout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        if(mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        int id = item.getItemId();


        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Below is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.lucy.zoo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105400/navigation-drawer-icon-not-showing-android

Comment: IIRC, DrawerLayout should be the root element

Comment: set `DrawerLayout` as parent/root  instead of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to fill items in list view than you have to assign list view to drawer layout.

to see this create new project from Android studio 
=>select Navigation drawer activity from Add activity to mobile  window

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should implement it.

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    
                mDrawerLayout,                    
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).commit();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

I have used the [following tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) to help me implement it. Hope it will help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerrrrFolder"
    >

<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">




         //your  whole layout comes here

    </RelativeLayout>




                        <!--Drawer LAyout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mydrawerFolder"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sslayoutmydrawerFolder"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/searcboxxxmydrawerFolder"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                                   >
                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editsearchtextmydrawerFolder"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:background="@drawable/drawwersearchback"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancelsearchboxlayoutmydrawerFolder"
                                        android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>



                                    <RelativeLayout
                                        android:id="@+id/cancelsearchboxlayoutmydrawerFolder"
                                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                        >
                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                                            android:background="@drawable/searchcancelicon"
                                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                                            />

                                    </RelativeLayout>


                                    <RelativeLayout
                                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

                                        >
                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                                            android:background="@drawable/drawersearchicon"
                                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                            />

                                    </RelativeLayout>

                                </RelativeLayout>








        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerlistitemsmydrawerFolder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sslayoutmydrawerFolder"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            >

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

hope you got this.