# i am using side menu screen and facing error related to getActionBar()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-navigation

Using navigation drawer for side menu screen but it is showing error Null pointer exception. I am attaching logcat please help me what is the solution for same?

The  problem is showing in action bar but I am not getting how to solve it?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import handyman.com.handyman.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import handyman.com.handyman.model.NavDrawerItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[]   navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

       /* // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menu, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
        loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });


        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentSignIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SigninActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignIn);
            }
        });



    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyOrders();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MyWallet();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new RateCard();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Offers();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Help();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Notifi();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
       getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="handyman.com.handyman">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

        <activity

            android:name="SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".SigninActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity

            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity

            android:name=".Profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error:

```
05-31 14:44:21.957 10898-10898/handyman.com.handyman E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: handyman.com.handyman, PID: 10898
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{handyman.com.handyman/handyman.com.handyman.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at handyman.com.handyman.MainActivity.setTitle(MainActivity.java:236)
                                                                           at handyman.com.handyman.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:225)
                                                                           at handyman.com.handyman.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you add your `styles.xml` file

Comment: make sure your `mTitle`  variable is null or not.?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi added

Comment: @AbhishekPatel didnot get you.

Comment: in your logcat you get `NullPointer` while you `setTitle`, so once check your `mTitle` string null or not.?

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I think It is not getting action bar while setting . But i am stuck with it after trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because of the `parent` theme being used in `styles.xml`,

you can use `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` here like

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"> <!-- Change here -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Previously set theme doesnot give access to `ActionBar` so its giving `NPE`

Comment: Thank you But now i am not getting side menu screen icon . removed NPE error. Could you please tell me that why it is not appearing menu screen for clicking .

Comment: `ActionBarDrawerToggle` you are talking about ?

Comment: you can follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385101/navigation-drawer-icon-ic-drawer-not-showing